# shadowRoot custom element not rendering content

Tags: shadow-dom, custom-element

First time with custom elements so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

I've got a simple custom element class that I'm inserting HTML into, but it doesn't render on the page. Any clues?

```js
class SearchBar extends HTMLElement{
    constructor(){
        super();
        var shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});

    shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
    <input type="text" class="video-input" placeholder="Enter a YouTube URL...">
    <style>.video-input{width: 100%; padding: 14px; font-size: 1.3em;color:white;}</style>
    `
    }
}

window.customElements.define("search-bar", SearchBar);
```

And the HTML:

```html
<div class="video-container">
     <search-bar></search-bar>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

White on white is not a good idea ;-)

Try another color.

```js
class SearchBar extends HTMLElement{
    constructor(){
        super();
        var shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});

    shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
    <input type="text" class="video-input" placeholder="Enter a YouTube URL...">
    <style>.video-input{width: 100%; padding: 14px; font-size: 1.3em;color:red;}</style>
    `
    }
}

window.customElements.define("search-bar", SearchBar);
```

```html
<div class="video-container">
     <search-bar></search-bar>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but it's rendering on top of a container with a background-color of black, so it's not that. In the developer tools the inspector doesn't even show the shadow-root property so it's not rendering at all.

Comment: @notmynamelastname look at the example in my post: it works. So the error should be elsewere but not in the code you provided